# Jupiter in Ubuntu 13.10 (Laptop Overheating)

Tags: power-management, overheating, 13.10, jupiter

I was wondering if Jupiter (Interface for display, power and device control) will work in Ubuntu 13.10, because my laptop (Toshiba Satellite C855D, AMD A6-4400M with Radeon HD Graphics running Ubuntu 13.04 x64) keeps overheating, I tried some other tools, like laptop-mode-tools or TLP, none of those work, not at all. Jupiter was the only option and it's supposedly discontinued, the version I'm using is being maintained by JoliCloud team, but they told me they're not sure if it will work with 13.10... If it doesn't work, I'm definitely not upgrading, since overheating is a major issue for me... Thanks in advance!

Comment: My macbook used to get a tad too warm under 11.04.  It definately handles the fans & idles a little differently than windows.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is add the repository from jolicloud. Here are the steps to install it on Ubuntu 13.10:

1. In the terminal enter:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jolicloud-team/ppa
   ```
2. Go to Software&Updates in Ubuntu
3. Then select *Other Software* tab
4. Then you want to click on http://ppa.launchpad.net/jolicloud-team/ppa/ubuntu
5. Then click *Edit*
6. Then in the Distribution box change `saucy` to `raring`. Then click okay and close Software&Updates.
7. Now in the terminal enter:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
8. Lastly in terminal enter:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install jupiter
   ```

Now you have installed Jupiter!

Comment: That's how I installed it in 13.04, but it doesn't work in 13.10...

Answer (score 1):

do not use jupiter. It does not work properly on 13.10. By the way I have gained approx. 1 hour more battery time by using this :

> sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools

Use TLP instead

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
>
> sudo tlp start

My system Lenovo G780 i7 / 8GB / dual hdd

Comment: You cannot use laptop-mode-tools and TLP at the same time: `Error: TLP power save is disabled because laptop-mode-tools is installed.
       Please uninstall laptop-mode-tools.`

Comment: I've already tried TLP and laptop-mode-tools, none of those work as I expect, my laptop keeps overheating when using one of those tools (as @don.joey says, they can't be used at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you can disable your Catalsyt card via AMD drivers in case you have installed them, usually it needs a sudo, also you will need to reboot. The system with then run on Intel graphics and with TLP, it will bring temps down.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran across a possible solution in the article:

http://www.techdrivein.com/2013/06/30-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu1304-raring.html

There is a program that they suggest as a replacement to Jupiter called TLP that is a power management applet for laptops and netbooks that prevents common overheating problems that might help, it's still being maintained unlike Jupiter so you'd be more likely to have success in the long run.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update

no need for anything else just add the repository and it should do the rest

Comment: TLP and laptop-mode-tools don't work...